# Validation of radio buttons with Javascript

Tags: javascript, radio-button, validation

I've combed a ton of the pages on here, and still am incapable to get my explicit validator to work. Basically, when the submit button is clicked, I want the script to verify a radio is checked, if one is checked to do nothing.  If one isn't checked I want it to post an alert message.

roughly my html looks like:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit = "check()">
<input type = "radio" name = "c" id = "1" value = "1" />
<input type = "radio" name = "c" id = "2" value = "2" />
<input type = "radio" name = "c" id = "3" value = "3" />

<input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
```

---

my JS page looks like:

```
function check() {
    var r = document.getElementsByName("c")
    var c = 0

    for(var i=0; i < r.length; i++){
       if(c[i].checked) {
          c = i; }
    }

    alert("please select radio");
}
```

Comment: http://www.chennaisunday.com/jsradio.html

Answer (score 4):

try this one

```
function check() {
var r = document.getElementsByName("c")
var c = -1

for(var i=0; i < r.length; i++){
   if(r[i].checked) {
      c = i; 
   }
}
if (c == -1) alert("please select radio");
}
```

Comment: Just tried this, still no alert.  The page basically just refreshes, like the script doesn't work.

Comment: @KelvinNguyen You need to return false if you don't want it to submit to server.

Answer (score 1):

this

```
c[i].check
```

should be

```
c[i].checked
```

and you're not actually doing anything with the result, you're just always alerting.

Comment: i changed the "checked."  I'm not doing anything with the result yet, I can't even get it to alert even though nothing is checked.

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if there are errors?  debugged?  etc..,

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function check()    {

chosen = ""
len = document.myform.chk.length

for (i = 0; i <len; i++) {
if (document.myform.chk[i].checked) {
chosen = document.myform.chk[i].value
}
}

if (chosen == "") {
alert("No Option selected");
return false;
}
else {
alert("option selected");
return true;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" onsubmit = "return check();">
<input type = "radio" name = "chk" id = "1" value = "1" >
<input type = "radio" name = "chk" id = "2" value = "2" >
<input type = "radio" name = "chk" id = "3" value = "3" >

<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Check for this validation hope its may also help you . Also check it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUQDL/)

Answer (score 0):

```
             function ShowMsg() {    

             if (fnSpeciality() == false) 
              {
              document.getElementById("myform").focus();
               return false;
            }

                function fnSpeciality() 
                {
             return fnRblfnSpeciality();
                 }
              function fnSpeciality() {
                   return fnRblfnSpeciality();
                          }


    function fnRblfnSpeciality() {

        var list = document.getElementById('myform'); //Client ID of the radiolist
        var inputs = list.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var isItemChecked = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            var listItem = inputs[i];

            if (listItem.checked) {
                //alert(listItem.value);
                isItemChecked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
     if (isItemChecked == false) {
            if (isItemChecked =="") {
                alert('Please select a speciality.');
                return false;
            }
            // else return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

CreditCard
                            DebitCard
                            By Cash

```
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Am using radio button list ..pls share if have java script validation for this radio button