# How do i put two different validation for two submit button in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a two submit button named Add and Search. When I click the Add submit button, its does the propoer validation using the validate method defined.
Now i have another Search submit button and also defined its function, but it is not working, i mean its not doing any validation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>INFORMATION</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function svalidate(){

   if (document.myForm.firstname.value=="" && document.myForm.lastname.value=="" &&     document.myForm.age.value=="" && document.myForm.gender.value==""){
       alert("Please enter any one value");
       return false;
   }   
}
function validate() {

    if (document.myForm.firstname.value==""){
        alert("Please provide the firstname");
        return false;   
    }

    if (document.myForm.lastname.value=="" ){
    alert("Please provide the lastname");
    return false;
    }

    if (document.myForm.age.value=="" || isNaN(document.myForm.age.value) ||     document.myForm.age.value<1){
    alert("Please provide the valid age in Integer");
    return false;
    }

    if (document.myForm.gender.value=""){
    alert("Please provide the gender");
    return false;
    }

}      
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action = "/~neeraj/cgi-bin/test.py" name="myForm" method="post">
            <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td> FirstName:* </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>LastName:* </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" name="lastname" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Age:* </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="age" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:* </td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ADD"     onclick="return(validate())">
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="RESET">
                <input type="submit" name="search" formmethod="post"     formaction="/~neeraj/cgi-bin/search.py" value="SEARCH" onclick="return(svalidate())">
        </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code is not working.

```
 if (document.myForm.gender.value=""){
    alert("Please provide the gender");
    return false;
```

You need to address you radio buttons like an array.

Refer this question to see how you can do this

[Validation of radio buttons with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14780387/validation-of-radio-buttons-with-javascript)

Change you Svalidate function to this

```
function svalidate(){    

    if (document.myForm.firstname.value=="" && document.myForm.lastname.value=="" && document.myForm.age.value=="" && ( document.myForm.gender[0].checked == "0") && ( document.myForm.gender[1].checked == "0")){
            alert("Please enter any one value");
            return false;   
        }   
    }
```

Also you will need to make the same change in your validate function. Check my [WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FJYJM/11/) To see both these changes...

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the [Radio button Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339073/radio-button-validation-in-javascript). This makes the condition false and the alert not running. The `document.myForm.gender.value` returns only `Undefined`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ( document.myForm.gender[0].checked == false ) && ( document.myForm.gender[1].checked == false ) ) 
{
alert ( "Please choose your Gender: Male or Female" ); 
return false;
}
```

use this coding for choose gender option...

function svalidate coding is here...

```
function svalidate(){    

    if (document.myForm.firstname.value=="" && document.myForm.lastname.value=="" && document.myForm.age.value=="" && ( document.myForm.gender[0].checked == false ) && ( document.myForm.gender[1].checked == false )){
            alert("Please enter any one value");
            return false;   
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested this?